# How to convert a byte array to sound without headers c#?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am using NAudio in my project to record sounds from the microphone. I want to convert the sounds to a byte array and then play them back. I am not using windows Forms instead i am doing it in a console application.

```
//get all the devices that can record audio
private List<WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<WaveInCapabilities>();

private List<string> Devices = new List<string>();
private List<string> Channels = new List<string>();

public void GetMicDevices()
{

    //get the capabilities of all the devices
    for(int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
    {
        sources.Add(WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
    }

    foreach(var i in sources)
    {
        Devices.Add(i.ProductName);
        Channels.Add(i.Channels.ToString());
    }

}

private WaveInEvent source = null;

public void StartMic()
{
    //set the device number
    int DeviceNum = 0;


    source = new WaveInEvent();

    //set the device number
    source.DeviceNumber = DeviceNum;

    //create the waveFormat                        num of channels for the device
    source.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(DeviceNum).Channels);


    //start the mic
    source.StartRecording();


}


//convert the sound into a byte array
//play the sound from the byte array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code and mostly used a memory stream, a Source_DataAvailable event 
here is the full working code :

```
 using NAudio.Utils;
 using NAudio.Wave;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApp2
 {
class Program
{
    private static List<WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<WaveInCapabilities>();

    private static List<string> Devices = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> Channels = new List<string>();
    static WaveInEvent source;
    static WaveOut _waveOut;
    static WaveFileWriter writer;
    static Stream memoryStream;
    static WaveFormat _waveFormat;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (memoryStream == null)
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        GetMicDevices();
        StartMic();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get all the devices that can record audio
    /// </summary>
    public static void GetMicDevices()
    {

        //get the capabilities of all the devices
        for (int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
        {
            sources.Add(WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
        }

        foreach (var i in sources)
        {
            Devices.Add(i.ProductName);
            Channels.Add(i.Channels.ToString());
        }

    }



    public static void StartMic()
    {
        //set the device number
        int DeviceNum = 0;


        source = new WaveInEvent();
        source.DataAvailable += Source_DataAvailable;
        source.RecordingStopped += Source_RecordingStopped;
        //set the device number
        source.DeviceNumber = DeviceNum;

        //create the waveFormat                        num of channels for the device
        _waveFormat= new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(DeviceNum).Channels);
        source.WaveFormat = _waveFormat;
        writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(memoryStream), _waveFormat);

        //start the mic
        Console.WriteLine("Start Rec");
        source.StartRecording();
        //record for 3 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        //stop the mic
        source.StopRecording();
        Console.WriteLine("End Rec");

        //play test
        Console.WriteLine("Play test");
        //play the sound from the byte array
        IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                     memoryStream, _waveFormat);
        _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        _waveOut.Init(provider);
        _waveOut.Play();

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();


    }

    private static void Source_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        source.Dispose();
        source = null;
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.Close();
           writer = null;
        }
    }

    private static void Source_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {   //convert the sound into a byte array
        writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks i finally get it. It helped a lot

Comment: it tells me that i cant because i dont have enough reputation. Sry